# Need to choose an appropriate solution on Azure

Tags: azure

I am working on an application that allows users to upload videos. These videos will be uploaded to Azure Storage Blob. Afterwards, I want to analyse the uploaded videos using a Python ML model.
How the code works is: first it will download the video from storage blob into a local folder, then analyse the video using the ML model, then after sending back the results it will clean up the local video folder.
What are some appropriate solutions on Azure for hosting the code and model?
I did try to read up on Azure Functions and some example scenarios, but none of them involve downloading video into a local folder, so I don't know if it is the solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any out of the box solution for your problem statement. But you can use multiple azure services to couple and form your solution.
Like

1. Video Upload to Blob Storage triggers
   a Azure functions.
2. Azure function downloads the video to
   function local storage.
3. Analyse the video using Python ML model.
4. Send the analytics result.
5. Clean up local folder.

Comment: Does Azure allow for me to download the video to Azure Function local storage?

Comment: Yes, it has. It has different plans and sizes, check this link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/storage-considerations